# C# Calculator - textBox to listBox

Tags: c#, button, textbox, listbox, calculator

This calculator is extremely basic and so I'm only working with two values to calculate at a time.

I am calculating two values only `val1` and `val2`. These values can be of any size including a decimal point.
I have buttons for numbers 0-9, a decimal point, plus, minus, divide, multiply and equals.

I want val1, val2 and the `operator(ex. +,-,/,*)` I choose to calculate these values to appear in my `listBox` after I hit the `=` button. Every calculation I make I want it added to the listBox underneath the previous calculation. When the listBox grows to a certain amount of calculations (10-15ish) I want the oldest calculation removed from the bottom and the newest added to the top of the list.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // global variables
    bool plus = false;
    bool minus = false;
    bool multiply = false;
    bool divide = false;
    bool equal = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    } // **MUST HAVE**

    private void button0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckIfEqual();
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "0";
    } // makes number click usable

    private void CheckIfEqual()
    {
        if (equal) // checks if equal is true
        {
            textBox1.Text = ""; // clear textBox
            equal = false; // tells program there is new calculation
        }
    } 

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckIfEqual();
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "1";
    } // makes number click usable

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckIfEqual();
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "2";
    } // makes number click usable

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckIfEqual();
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "3";
    } // makes number click usable

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckIfEqual();
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "4";
    } // makes number click usable

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckIfEqual();
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "5";
    } // makes number click usable

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckIfEqual();
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "6";
    } // makes number click usable

    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckIfEqual();
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "7";
    } // makes number click usable

    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckIfEqual();
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "8";
    } // makes number click usable

    private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckIfEqual();
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "9";
    } // makes number click usable


    private void buttonDecimal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckIfEqual();
        if (textBox1.Text.Contains("."))
        {
            return;
        } // if it contains a decimal execute 
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + ".";
        } // adds decimal
      } // end decimal

    private void buttonPlusMinus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Contains("-"))
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Remove(0, 1);
        } // if it contains the - character remove it
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = "-" + textBox1.Text;
        } //
    } // adds/removes -

    private void buttonPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            return;
        } // if textbox is empty return
        else
        {
            plus = true;
            textBox1.Tag = textBox1.Text; // stores number 
            textBox1.Text = ""; // clears textbox
        } // tells program we are adding
    } // end plus

    private void buttonMinus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            return;
        } // if textbox is empty return
        else
        {
            minus = true;
            textBox1.Tag = textBox1.Text; // stores number 
            textBox1.Text = ""; // clears textbox
        } // tells program we are subtracting

    }

    private void buttonMultiply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            return;
        } // if textbox is empty return
        else
        {
            multiply = true;
            textBox1.Tag = textBox1.Text; // stores number 
            textBox1.Text = ""; // clears textbox
        } // tells program we are multiplying
    }

    private void buttonDivide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            return;
        } // if textbox is empty return
        else
        {
            divide = true;
            textBox1.Tag = textBox1.Text; // stores number 
            textBox1.Text = ""; // clears textbox
        } // tells program we are dividing
    }

    private void buttonEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        equal = true; // tells program it made a calculation
        if (plus) // if true execute
        {
            decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Tag) + Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
            textBox1.Text = dec.ToString(); // display value once add is finished
            plus = false;
        } // end if plus

        if (minus) // if true execute
        {
            decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Tag) - Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
            textBox1.Text = dec.ToString(); // display value once add is finished
            minus = false;
        } // end if minus

        if (multiply) // if true execute
        {
            decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Tag) * Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
            textBox1.Text = dec.ToString(); // display value once add is finished
            multiply = false;
        } // end if multiply

        try
        {
            if (divide) // if true execute
            {
                decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Tag) / Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
                textBox1.Text = dec.ToString(); // display value once add is finished
                divide = false;
            } // end if divide
        } // try
        catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        } // catch
     } // end buttonEquals

    private void buttonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        plus = minus = multiply = divide = false; // makes all false regardless
        textBox1.Text = ""; // clear
        textBox1.Tag = ""; // clears
    }


    } // end partial class Form1
}// end namespace
```

Comment: do you have anything so far?

Comment: what happens if user wanna make 2 + 22 ? What exact event(s) should fire "put me in the ListBox" ?

Comment: have you started doing any of the coding yourself..? look at the things you stated that you would like to have .. a Button a few Textboxes etc... you have to make an attempt to try coding on your own first

Comment: @haxx - yup I have the calculator portion working the way I would like..@Rahael - I guess to clarify the "value" can be as large as you want. What I was trying to say was that you cant calculate something like " 10+25+60" if that makes sense. The "=" button is what will be the trigger to send to ListBox

Comment: why can't you add three integers? is that the problem? could you try to rephrase the question because I'm afraid "we" don't get it :)

Comment: question has been re-phrased

Comment: if you have something working currently..how about post your code here so we can see what it is you are trying to do, and we can guide you much better..

Comment: it sound like assignment for a student :D

Answer (score 2):

Refactoring would be nice...

For example, you can use the same method for all your "numeric button click" event.

instead of

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckIfEqual();
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "1";
    } // makes number click usable

...
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckIfEqual();
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "9";
    } // makes number click usable
```

just use one method.

```
button1.Click += NumericButtonClick;
...
button9.Click +=NumericButtonClick;


private void NumericButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        CheckIfEqual();
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + ((Button)sender).Text;
}
```

Anyway.

Say you have a ListBox historyListBox;

Then just add a method

```
private void PopulateListBox(string left, string right, string operator) {
  var newContent = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", left, operator, right);
  if (historyListBox.Items.Count == 15)
    historyListBox.Items.RemoveAt(14);//

  historyListBox.Items.Insert(0, newContent);

}
```

and then you could change the "equal_click event" (which sould be also refactored, but that's another problem)

```
private void buttonEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var left = textBox1.Tag;
        var right = textBox1.Text;
        var operator = string.Empty;
        equal = true; // tells program it made a calculation
        if (plus) // if true execute
        {
            operator = "+";
            decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal(left) + Convert.ToDecimal(right);
            textBox1.Text = dec.ToString(); // display value once add is finished
            plus = false;
        } // end if plus

        if (minus) // if true execute
        {
            operator = "-";
            decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal(left) - Convert.ToDecimal(right);
            textBox1.Text = dec.ToString(); // display value once add is finished
            minus = false;
        } // end if minus

        //...etc

       PopulateListBox(left, right, operator);
   }
```

Comment: I was just crafting the same exact answer GMTA!

Comment: @Raphael.. are you putting "button1.Click += NumericButtonClick;" inside the NumericButtonClick method? Just want to clarify.

Comment: @Golf_pro90 no. It's the "event registration",  probably in Initialization in your code : replace the `button1.Click += new EventHandler(this.button0_Click);` (untill button9) by this.

Comment: @Raphael - my comment was meant to be a complement.